# Create webpage that becomes "app" when is added as bookmark in homepage's mobile phone

Tags: html

I want to do some tests in order to learn more about webpage design, and I'm asking (and I didn't find on internet) why there are webpages that allows "save as bookmark" and become "applications" and there are some that not.

As example, I have two webpages. The first one is this, stackoverflow.com. I visit the page with my mobile browser app and I add it in my mobile phone's homepage.
I do the same with other web, concretely eltiempo.es.

In my mobile's home I have the next image:
[image: Home]

It seems to be the same behaviour, but here is my doubt. If I press on Stackoverflow's bookmark, i visit the web within my mobile's browser app, as the next image shows:
[image: stackoverflow web]

But if I visit eltiempo.es with the bookmark, it seems to be an application (see next image):
[image: eltiempo.es]

And my question is... what is the difference between both webs. I know they are not developed with the same language but, why eltiempo.es' webpage has this behaviour?
I would like to develop a web that allows it.

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Regards,
Miquel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these meta tags to your page:

```html
<!-- iOS -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<!-- Android -->
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! And for android and other devices?

Comment: @msabate see updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll mark your answer as the correct one :)